# Assigning values with both boolean masking and indexing

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following toy example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([0,1,2,3,4,5,6], columns=['Value'])
df_subset = df.loc[[3,4,5]]

df.loc[df.Value % 2 == 0, 'Value'] = df_subset.Value * 10
```

**df before assignment:**

```
 0. 0
 1. 1
 2. 2
 3. 3
 4. 4
 5. 5
 6. 6
```

**df after assignment:**

```
 0. NaN
 1. 1
 2. NaN
 3. 3
 4. 40
 5. 5
 6. NaN
```

---

This happens due to the following reason:

- Only items for which the mask / boolean index is true are modified, i.e only even elements
- This is the reason why `idx=1` is not set to NaN
- Any indices which don't appear in the index of the right hand side are set to NaN

What I want to achieve however is the same behaviour without setting missing index entries to NaN, i.e

- Modify elements for which the mask is true
- For those elements: Replace a value in `df` with that in `df_subset` if the particular index is part of `df.index`

**desired output:**

```
 0. 0
 1. 1
 2. 2
 3. 3
 4. 40
 5. 5
 6. 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First idea is chain both masks by `&` for bitwise `AND`, for test index is used [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([0,1,2,3,4,5,6], columns=['Value'])
df_subset = df.loc[[3,4,5]]

mask = (df.Value % 2 == 0) & (df.index.isin([3,4,5]))
df.loc[mask, 'Value'] = df_subset.Value * 10

print (df)
   Value
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
4     40
5      5
6      6
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([0,1,2,3,4,5,6], columns=['Value'])
mask = (df.Value % 2 == 0) & (df.index.isin([3,4,5]))
df.loc[mask, 'Value'] *= 10

print (df)
   Value
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
4     40
5      5
6      6
```

Another idea is filter subset by original mask and use [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([0,1,2,3,4,5,6], columns=['Value'])
df_subset = df.loc[[3,4,5]]

df.update(df_subset.loc[df.Value % 2 == 0, 'Value'] * 10)

#alternative
#df.update(df_subset.loc[df_subset.Value % 2 == 0, 'Value'] * 10)

print (df)
   Value
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    3.0
4   40.0
5    5.0
6    6.0
```

Comment: I believe this will be infeasable due to the `isin()` operation if the index or the subgroup contains e.g multiple million entries. Care to elaborate on this topic?

Comment: Great, I believe `update()` is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you

Comment: I did some quick benchmarks and it turns out that despite my initial intuition the `isin()` variant (**16.4 ms**) is almost twice as fast as the `update()` variant (**29.6 ms**) for a DataFrame with 10^6 entries and a suggroup of 3*10^4 entries (I made sure to use an `Int64Index` opposed to `RangeIndex` for the subgroup)

Comment: **Note**: This does not hold for even bigger dataframes (10^7 and subgroup 3*10^5). In that case `update()` provides an speedup of 2-3. Subgroup size seems almost irrelevant though, there appears to be no almost no difference betwenn 10^4 and 3*10^5.